# How to set variable to the total amount of questions

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[enter image description here][1]I'm having trouble finding the total amount of questions on a Dataframe. My script is the following:

```
for month in month_unique:
    month_data = data.loc[data['Month'] == month]
    for week in week_unique:
        groups = month_data.loc[month_data['Week'] == week]
        scale = groups.groupby(['Clusters', 'Day'])['Clusters'].count().unstack('Clusters').fillna(0)
```

Where month_unique is each month and week_unique is the week number of that month. The concept of this loop is to enter those variables to fetch data specific for that. If I do `print(scale.info)` I get the following:

```
<bound method DataFrame.info of Clusters  Grafana  Logs  Topic
Day                           
Fri           1.0   1.0    0.0
Thu           0.0   0.0    1.0>
```

The only idea I got to set the total number of data to a variable is `number = scale.dtypes.value_counts()` which didn't get me a value of 3, but `float64 3 dtype: int64` Any advice on how to go about this?

This is the output when I do `print(scale.info())`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2 entries, Fri to Thu
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Grafana    2 non-null float64
Logs       2 non-null float64
Topic      2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 64.0+ bytes
None
```

This is the data from the .csv file that I've been using:

```
Clusters  Questions     Month   Day  Date       Week
Topic     set the       January Thu  01/04/2018 1
Grafana   My team is    January Fri  01/05/2018 1
Logs      not seeing    January Fri  01/05/2018 1
```

I want the output to look something like this graph (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgf4X.png), but everything before the text 'Questions' be the number 3

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your input dataframe, and a desired output?

Comment: `print(scale.info())`

Comment: Post your example data frame, and put what you are trying to do into a single statement. Do you want the total number of questions, or the number of questions for each week?

Comment: I've applied your revision.

Comment: I have solved my issue. All I need was to put len(groups) and set that to a variable.